# xpath last link on wikimedia dumps

Tags: ruby, xpath, mechanize

How would you go in getting the latest download link for pagecounts from

```
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2011/2011-11/
```

using XPath?

```
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2011/2011-11/pagecounts-20111115-140000.gz
```

I went with (Mechanize):

```
agent.get(url).search("//*[@href[contains(.,'pagecounts')]]")#.last
```

But I still have troubles getting the last element in the XPath expression.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2, Ruby 1.9.3-p0, Mechanize 2.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the last node from a collection in XPath, use

```
[position()=last()]
```

or even just

```
[last()]
```

As you want to retrieve the last anchor from the entire document set, use this (tested in PHP but it should do in Mechanize)

```
(//a[starts-with(@href, 'pagecounts')])[last()]
```

Comment: this is something that I already tried, but Mechanize (using Nokogiri) returns a full collection instead of the last element, not sure why. Hence why I started using .last directly in ruby.

Comment: @kain I've updated my answer. Not the cleanest markup going on there :)

Comment: honest, that's another thing I already tried, and gives me http://pastie.org/2871048
That's why I'm asking on SO :)

Comment: @kain Looks like a broken XPath implementation in that case

Comment: @Phil may be right. Mechanize uses Nokogiri by default, and Nokogiri is based on libxml2. The version of libxml2 that comes with OS X is known to have problems. Upgrading libxml fixes a lot.

Comment: @Mark Thomas, I installed libxml2 from homebrew but perhaps you are right since the formula is keg-only. I may have to try to recompile the nokogiri dependence with a custom path using /usr/local/Cellar... This is however more trouble than it's worth, so I'm going to close the question. Cheers!